# Determine the minimum distance between 2 parallel lines by using vectors

Tags: vectors

I am trying to find the minimum distance between these 2 parallel lines:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8fKt.png)

I have thought of trying to find the perpendicular distance between these 2 lines (this is the minimum distance). So, I found a perpendicular vector to the direction vector of L1 <1, 2, 1> and then tried to find out the vector equation of the perpendicular line L3 to both L1 and L2 that passes through point A (3,2,-1). It is supposed to be <3,2,1> + s<1,2,1> Then I tried to find the intersection between L2 and L3, in order to determine the distance.

Can you please help to find out why this solution is wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwdLK.png)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I think you can do the following: replace L1 through the origin, i.e. subtract its coordinates for $\lambda=0$ from L2. Then choose $\lambda=1$ so L1 is a vector from the origin to (2,-2, 2). Then calculate the $\mu$ for which L2 has a zero dot-product with L1=(2,-2, 2). The length of L2 for that $\mu$ then is the minimum distance. I get $\mu=-2$ and distance $3\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You found $L_3$ as having parametric form $(3,2, -1) + s(1,2,1)$ (you left off a "-" sign in what you wrote here, but it is in your image, so I assume that was a typo). And you've indicated the correct next step for this approach: find the intersection of $L_2$ and $L_3$. That part is all correct (other than the typo) for this method of finding the solution. But you haven't told what intersection you found, nor what distance you calculated from it. So apparently, you messed up in the part that you did not reproduce here.